# PHP mail() not sending emails Centos Cloud Server

Tags: php, email, centos5, magento

I am new to this. Have got a cloudserver running centos 5.4, Installed php, mysql and apache to run magento however emails are not going out.. Do I need to configure something more?

Answer (score 1):

PHP mail function depends only on two things:

- PHP config (search for `mail` keyword in `php.ini`)
- Sendmail

Mail transport is a different question and if you don't have any errors after your PHP script sends the email, you could check:

- `mailq`, if queue is not empty, possibly there is firewall issue
- `tail /var/log/mail`, log checking :-)

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your reply.

I checked /var/log/maillog and its empty.

php.ini under [mail function]:

sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i

but in /usr/sbin there is no sendmail, maybe I need to install this first?

Comment: Yes. Or check the command 'whereis sendmail` in case if sendmail is installed in different place.

Comment: You could also install something else. Other MTAs also offer sendmail compatible `sendmail` commands.